# Java Project with modules in one Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project called BigProject.

The structure is:

```
BigProject
-firstModule
 --pom.xml
-secondModule
 --pom.xml
-thirdModule
 --pom.xml
-pom.xml
```

I want to create a unique jar called BigProject.jar 
At the moment, if I do a clean install, I have returned a jar for each module.

Can you explain me how to do?
thanks

Comment: The usual approach is to have a "bundle" or "launcher" module that includes the other ones. Try looking for the term *fat jar*.

Comment: The question is: Do you mean module in the meaning of JPMS module? If yes creating a ueber-jar will not make sense and will break the separation in itself. If you mean just a ueber-jar / executeable jar? This can be achieved by using maven-assembly-plugin (jar-with-dependencies) or via maven-shade-plugin with more fine control...

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd need a custom class loader for that. Thankfully folks have already contributed some plugins to ease up your life. You can have a look over Ant's create jar task or spring-boot's repackage goal, whatever stays convenient for you. Example below:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each **`module-info.java`** which lives in the **default package** will be compiled to **`module-info.class`**.

Therefore, **one JAR cannot contain multiple modules**.